# Genero un Json y no presenta nada

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

he estado trabajando en el codigo de abajo, pero el problema es q cuando lo ejecuto, no me presenta nada, la tabla y la base de datos funcionan
quiero generar un JSON

```
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','esports');
    $myArray = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM jugador")) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $myArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($myArray);
    }

    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();

     ?>
```

Comment: la consulta SQL en tu gestor de bases de datos si devuelve registros?

Comment: si, cuando registro select * from jugador devuleve la fila

Answer (score 1):

Realiza tu consulta de este modo:

```
<?php 

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','esports');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM jugador");

$myArray = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $myArray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

- Dentro del *while* usa el método `fetch_assoc` para indicar que el resultado devuelto se trate como un array asociativo; es decir en formato de `clave => valor`
- Iguala por dentro del while el array vacío `$resultado` con los valores obtenidos por la consulta a la BD.
- Imprime por fuera dentro de la función `json_encode()` el array que se llenó con los datos de la consulta dentro del while.
- Opcionalmente usa la constante `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` para darle un formato mas legible a la salida; aclarando que esto es totalmente opcional.

Dando un resultado similar a este:

```
[
    {
        "columna1": "valor1",
        "columna2": "valor2"
    },
    {
        "columna1": "valor3",
        "columna2": "valor4"
    }
]
```

Comment: No an no presenta nada, pero proble con: fetch_row() en vez de fetch assoc y funciona, pero solo arroja el valor, no la clave, alguna idea ?

Comment: probaste haciendo las modificaciones de usar `fetch_assoc()` @CarlosJuca ?, por que he realizado un ejemplo en local y me es totalmente funcional

Comment: si lo probe, pero igual no prensentaba el JSON

Comment: realiza después del while un `var_dump($myArray);` y dime te devuelve algo? @CarlosJuca

Comment: me devolvio esto `array(0) { } array(1) { [0]=> array(20) { [0]=> string(1) "7" ["idjugador"]=> string(1) "7" [1]=> string(4) "1101" ["cedula"]=> string(4) "1101" [2]=> string(6) "Carlos" ["nombres"]=> string(6) "Carlos" [3]=> string(4) "Juca" ["apellidos"]=> string(4) "Juca" [4]=> string(4) "1234" ["contrase�a"]=> string(4) "1234" [5]=> string(1) "1" ["estado"]=> string(1) "1" [6]=> string(1) "1" ["funcion"]=> string(1) "1" [7]=> string(6) "  ` Algo asi

Comment: es raro que entonces no te devuelva nada si con la consulta si estás obteniendo la data de tu bd, entonces quitando ese var_dump() y haciendo `echo json_encode($myArray);` te debería mostrar tus datos como un json @CarlosJuca

Comment: lo termine realizando de esta manera `$myArray = array('idjugador' => $row[0]`

Comment: @CarlosJuca considera entonces publicar y explicar tu respuesta para que los demás conozcamos lo que hiciste para solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el siguiente código

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

después de la etiqueta  `<?php`